# Command to input a set of coordinates and plot them

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given below is the code I used to draw a signal plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
{\tikz{%
\draw[thick, -Latex] ({-4-1.5},0) -- ({4+1.5},0);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (0,-4) node[below] {} -- (0,1) node[right] {$-3+x(t)$};
\node[anchor=north west] at (0,0){Time, $t \rightarrow$};
\draw [thick](-4,-3) node[below right]{$-3$}  -- (-2,-3) node[below right]{} |- (-2,-1) --(0,-1) node[below left] {$-1$}--(2,-1) -|(2,-3) node[below left] {$$} -- (4,-3)node[below left] {$$};
    }
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Since I need to draw many, many more is there any way I can just input the coordinates as (x1,y1),(x2,y2)....(xn,yn) and get tikz to join them?  I would also need to specify the axis labels. 
For example, can I define a command (say,\sigplot) or a style so that I can just type

```
\sigplot{-3+x(t)}{(-4,0),(-2,0),(-2,1),(2,1),(2,0),(4,0)} 
% the number of points might vary
```

and get the same results?
P.S. My knowledge of tikz is rudimentary. Would appreciate it if someone would spell it out for me

Comment: @cfr Added the complete code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can remove the commas in between it is easy.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\sigplot#1#2{%
\draw[thick, -Latex] ({-4-1.5},0) -- ({4+1.5},0);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (0,-4) node[below] {} -- (0,1) node[right] {#1};
\node[anchor=north west] at (0,0){Time, $t \rightarrow$};
\draw plot coordinates {#2};
 }
\sigplot{$-3+x(t)$}{(-4,0) (-2,0) (-2,1) (2,1) (2,0) (4,0)} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But pgfplots does all and much more

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines*=center]
\addplot+[] coordinates {(-4,0) (-2,0) (-2,1) (2,1) (2,0) (4,0)} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

try this (without text on line)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

 \newcommand{\sigplot}[2]{
 \draw[thick, ->] ({-4-1.5},0) -- ({4+1.5},0);
\draw[thick, ->] (0,-4) node[below] {} -- (0,1) node[right] {$#1$};
\node[anchor=north west] at (0,0){Time, $t \rightarrow$};
 \newcommand*{\lastcoord}{}
 \foreach \coord [remember=\coord as \lastcoord]  in {#2}{
\draw \lastcoord -- \coord;
 };
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \sigplot{-3+x(t)}{(-4,-3),(-2,-3),(-2,-1),(0,-1),(2,-1),(2,-3),(4,-3)}
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```